# Get individual value from the List created using SQFLITE

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, sqflite

I have come up with an app that takes title and description from the user as inputs and stores it locally using sqflite. Whenever user presses save button I should be able to Either create the list of title only or description only or both in card widget.
I tired this **child: Text(notes[NoteFields.description]),**  in buildNotes method but I am unable to retrieve list of description but I am getting type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

```
class NotesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotesPageState createState() => _NotesPageState();
}

class _NotesPageState extends State<NotesPage> {
  late List<Note> notes;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    refreshNotes();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    NotesDatabase.instance.close();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future refreshNotes() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);

    this.notes = await NotesDatabase.instance.readAllNotes();

    setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'Notes',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
      actions: [Icon(Icons.search), SizedBox(width: 12)],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: isLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : notes.isEmpty
          ? Text(
        'No Notes',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
      )
          : buildNotes(notes),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEditNotePage()),
        );

        refreshNotes();
      },
    ),
  );

  Widget buildNotes(notes) =>

        Card(


          child: Text(notes[NoteFields.description]),

        );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

notes is a List, use listview builder widget to render list object

```
 ListView.builder(
   itemCount: notes.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     Card(
        child: Text(notes[index][NoteFields.description]),
     );
   });
```

or use integer index to get specific value like

```
 Card(
        child: Text(notes[0][NoteFields.description]),
 );
```